# How to plot the derivative of a function in Tikz that is given via data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Assume we have a data `data.csv` of a function in the form of two columns: x and f(x), e.g.,

```
x f
0 3
0.25 2
0.5 2
0.75 0
1 1
```

The by default representation of it via `\addplot` in TikZ is given as a piecewise-linear function connecting each consecutive two points by segments:

```
\addplot[color=blue!50, line width=1.5,] table[x={x}, y={f}]{data.csv}
```

I want its derivative's representation via an `\addplot` like function, without generating an auxiliar data from `data.csv`. More specifically, I want an automate TikZ program that given the data returns the piecewise-constant plot of the derivative. For the previous data example, the plot of:

f(x) = (2-3)/(0.25-0) if 0<x<0.25, (2-2)/(0.5-0.25) if 0.25<x<0.5, (0-2)/(0.75-0.5) if 0.5<x<0.75, (1-0)/(1-0.75) if 0.75<x<1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
x f
0 3
0.25 2
0.5 2
0.75 0
1 1 
}\mydata

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  create col/assign/.code={
  \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
  \pgfmathsetmacro\tmpish{(\nextrow{f}-\thisrow{f})/(\nextrow{x}-\thisrow{x})}
    \else
  \pgfmathsetmacro\tmpish{(\thisrow{f}-\prevrow{f})/(\thisrow{x}-\prevrow{x})}
  \fi
  \edef\entry{\tmpish}%
  \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
  }
]{dfdx}{\mydata}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick distance=0.25, ytick distance=1, grid]
\addplot table {\mydata};

% use jump mark right instead of const plot mark right if you
% don't want the vertical lines
\addplot +[const plot mark right, mark=none, ultra thick] table[x=x,y=dfdx] {\mydata};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, in general it's always nice if you make a minimal example.  In this case it could something like the code above, just without the stuff that makes the new column and adds the second plot.